# Why Does Git Merge not Auto-generate a Commit and Commit Message?

Tags: git, git-merge

I am trying to learn branching and merging in git. I thought that merging 2 branches automatically generates a merge commit and message (which I regard as a good thing). I DO want a commit and a commit message automatically generated, preferably with the ability to edit the commit message.

I made a "test" branch, deleted two non-critical files, commited, and then merged test back into master. I do not get a commit or a commit message for the merge; instead HEAD (on master) becomes the last commit from the test branch.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way of forcing it to automatically generate a commit with each merge, preferably allowing me to edit the commit message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing no files had to be merged when you merged the two branches. If the current state of a branch is just a series of commits based on the head of another branch, a so-called fast-forward merge is performed. See also [here](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html) (at the very bottom), it's explained better than I could do it

Answer (score 9):

You can use `git merge --no-ff` to avoid performing a fast-forward merge and thus always creating a merge commit.